# Setting PORTA of a PIC16F877a as digital

Tags: microcontroller, pic, pic16f877a

I have an LCD hooked up to the A ports of a PIC16F877a (A0, A1, A2 etc). However, the display doesn't work because PORTA is configured as analog by default.

In an PIC18F46K22 I'd do it using ANSELA = 0x00; but there is no such option in the PIC16F877A. I looked everywhere on the internet and some solutions suggested turning off the ADCON1 and bits, but nothing, ABSOLUTELY nothing works.

**I changed the connection pins to PORTD (D0, D1, D2 etc) and it worked just fine.** The problem is the analog configuration of PORTA which I can't change no matter what I try.

I am using MikroC for the program and here's my code:

```
sbit LCD_RS at RA0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN at RA1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4 at RA2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5 at RA3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6 at RA4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7 at RA5_bit;

// Pin direction
sbit LCD_RS_Direction at TRISA0_bit;
sbit LCD_EN_Direction at TRISA1_bit;
sbit LCD_D4_Direction at TRISA2_bit;
sbit LCD_D5_Direction at TRISA3_bit;
sbit LCD_D6_Direction at TRISA4_bit;
sbit LCD_D7_Direction at TRISA5_bit;

void main()
{

     ADCON1 = 0x00;
     ADCON0 = 0x00;
     TRISA = 0x00;
    Lcd_Init();
    while (1)
    {
      Lcd_Out(1,1,"Hello");
      Lcd_Out(2,1,"World");
    }
}
```

This site is my last hope, I don't even know if there's another human who uses this microcontroller in 2023 :D

EDIT: ANSELH doesn't exist either. Even ChatGPT fails to solve this issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are setting `ADCON1` incorrectly. Have a look in the example assembly code for `PORTA` initialisation in the [datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/39582b.pdf):

[image: ADCON1 initialisation]

This corresponds to `0b0000_0110` being written to the `ADCON1` register. Cross referencing that with register description in `REGISTER 11-2`:

[image: PCFG[3:0]]

shows this is the value required to set all of `PORTA` to digital.

Beyond that, pin `RA4` is not a push-pull output - it is an open drain output (note the schematic is wrong, the output from the registers is actually `!Q` not `Q`):

[image: RA4 schematic view]

This means it can only pull the output to ground. You might be able to solve the problem by putting a pull up resistor from `RA4` to `VCC`.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I did look at that part of the datasheet and updated my code accordingly. It still doesn't work as expected. I went the extra mile and disabled other multiplexed functions still to no avail. I guess It's time to look into "project settings" and all. Thanks again.

Comment: Odd  - have you tried writing `0x00` to `PORTA` to initialise it as well as shown in the assembly example (`CLRF PORTA`)? Bit 5 is `x` at reset, which might affect the LCD init routine. Might be worth disconnecting the LCD and just trying to get some LEDs blinking!

Comment: Yep, I did that as well, still didnt' work. At this point it's worth mentioning that after reconnecting the pins to PORTD everything once again works fine.

Comment: Ah - there's the problem - `RA4` is an open drain output, not a push pull. It won't drive the `LCD_D6` pin correctly. I'll edit the answer to reflect that...

Comment: That solves the issue. I'm kind of glad the solution was something I couldn't have come up with since I'm only a sophomore-year intern and I thank you for your answer.

Comment: You're welcome - enjoy the rest of the project!